# Storage Account ARM template allowing traffic from entire virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to allow traffic in an a storage account created with an ARM template from the ENTIRE vnet? I currently have this:

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "kind": "Storage",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[variables('nsg-storage-account-name')]",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [
            {
              "id": "[ variables('vnet_storageSubnetId') ]",
              "action": "Allow"
            }
          ],
          "defaultAction": "Deny"
        }
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountType')]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    }
```

Which is making me select a specific subnet, but I would like an entire VNET as there around almost 20 subnets I will have to include

Answer (score 0):

A network security group can be associated to a network interface, the subnet the network interface is in, or both.  This is why it's asking you for the subnet, there is no option to apply an NSG to the entire VNet.

You can configure storage accounts to allow access only from specific VNets.

Enable a Service endpoint for Azure Storage within the VNet. This endpoint gives traffic an optimal route to the Azure Storage service. The identities of the virtual network and the subnet are also transmitted with each request. Administrators can then configure network rules for the storage account that allow requests to be received from specific subnets in the VNet. Clients granted access via these network rules must continue to meet the authorization requirements of the storage account to access the data.

Each storage account supports up to 100 virtual network rules, which may be combined with IP network rules.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-network%2ftoc.json#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-vnet-plan-design-arm

Answer (score 0):

to add to existing answer. you need to build an array with each subnet, you would also need to repeat this on the vnet\subnet side (enabled service endpoints).